# Is suggestion user specific?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, enterprise-search

Let us know the suggestions API result is user specific, or not if suggestion text query not configured in the central admin?

As we found below link.but not mentioned anything about user specific.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj721441.aspx

Please see below brief details.

We are implementing "`Related Search`", In this implementation, we want to display links that users had searched and visited (in some articles mentioned if the user clicked a link 6 time then this link will be added into suggestion). We are using the `/_api/search/suggest?querytext='sharepoint'` API call. Right now it returns only current users visited/clicked links. We want to display links which are visited/clicked (6-times) by all users. Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score -1):

Please see below link.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc295d1b-68e2-4637-868c-03ce9746c781/query-suggestions-api-result-is-user-specific?forum=sharepointsearch

Regards,

Vikas